# how to keep command line options but add more optimization flag to certain function in gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization

An easy example:

```
auto f(double*a,unsigned long const N)
{
   for(auto i(0);i!=N;++i) a[i]+=2*i;
}
```

and then I use g++ -std=c++1z -O2 -march=native -ftree-vectorize -fopt-info -S to compile the source code. The output show: note loop vectorized. That is good.

After that I want to add more aggressive optimization to such function. So I write:

```
__attribute__((optimize("unroll-loops"))) auto f(double*a,unsigned long const N)
{
  for(auto i(0);i!=N;++i) a[i]+=2*i;
}
```

and then I use g++ -std=c++1z -O2 -march=native -ftree-vectorize -fopt-info -S to compile the source code. The output just show: note loop unroll 7 times. And then I check the asm file and find out that gcc just does unroll-loops optimization but ignores tree-vectorize in the command line.

I also try to use:

```
#pragma GCC optimize("unroll-loops")
auto f(double*a,unsigned long const N)
{
  for(auto i(0);i!=N;++i) a[i]+=2*i;
}
```

still not working. So I want to ask how to keep command line options but add more optimization flag to certain function.

I use g++-5.2, x86-64 linux and cpu support avx2.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using `-O3`?  It doesn't enable `-funroll-loops` these days, so it doesn't gratuitously bloat your code.

Comment: I want to use unroll-loops to such function, -O3 not include -funroll-loops

Comment: Right, but `-O3` does enable other useful optimizations that can help all your functions, not just the ones that you want unrolled.  My point was, why only `-O2`, now that `-O3` is less likely to make things worse instead of better?

Comment: Well, O2 can guarantee that the binary code is faster. But O3 may get faster or slower. Most important, I do not know how the O3 additional flags affect the asm file. [https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) says everything about what O3 does, but still too abstract.

Comment: Well, enjoy your non-vectorized code, then.  Now that `-funroll-loops` isn't enabled by `-O3`, I think it's appropriate for general use, even though I don't understand exactly what all of the extra optimizations do, either.  (Your idea of enabling `unroll-loops` for a few specific functions is a good one, though, esp. if you can't easily use `-fprofile-generate` and `-fprofile-use`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes) documentation...

> *optimize*
>
> The optimize attribute is used to specify that a function is to be compiled with different optimization options than specified on the command line. Arguments can either be numbers or strings. Numbers are assumed to be an optimization level. Strings that begin with O are assumed to be an optimization option, while other options are assumed to be used with a -f prefix. You can also use the ‘#pragma GCC optimize’ pragma to set the optimization options that affect more than one function. See Function Specific Option Pragmas, for details about the ‘#pragma GCC optimize’ pragma.

So, the *optimize* attribute  and the `#pragma` are not additive.  You would have to explicitly pass all the necessary optimization arguments to the attribute.

For example...

```
__attribute__((optimize("O2", "tree-vectorize", "unroll-loops"))) auto f(double*a,unsigned long const N)
{
  for(auto i(0);i!=N;++i) a[i]+=2*i;
}
```

However, you may get better results using PGO instead of explicitly forcing the compiler to use specific optimizations.

Comment: No, I try to use g++ -std=c++1z -O2 -march=native -ftree-vectorize -fopt-info -S to compile the function with __attribute__((optimize("O2", "tree-vectorize", "unroll-loops"))). Answer still the same, output just shows: note loop unroll 7 times. It still ingnore tree-vectorize.

Comment: @ken That's the correct way to apply the optimization to the function, so GCC probably either thinks it isn't a valid optimization with the given code or can't vectorize it.  You may want to try applying `-ftree-vectorize` globally and see if it makes a difference or even using `clang` instead.  The loop count is dynamic though so you also may get a different result inlining the function, using LTO, or possibly even duff's device.  If absolutely necessary, it may be easier to just manually vectorize.